# Searching by letters in Postgresql vs. sqlite3 in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, heroku, sqlite

I am having trouble searching a string by the first letters. For example, if I have "animal", "ant", and "abs" in my database, I would like a query of "an" to return "animal" and "ant" (case insensitive). I got this working just fine with sqlite3:

`Thing.where("name LIKE ?", params[:query] + '%')`

However, this **does not work in PostgreSQL** (database used in pushing to Heroku). What is the correct query using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will be:

```
Thing.where("name LIKE '?%'", params[:query])
```

This makes the query `case insensitive`:

```
Thing.where("lower(name) LIKE '?%'", params[:query].to_s.downcase)
```

If your production uses Postgres, I recommend development does it also, to prevent a further error like this!

Comment: Ah just figured it out. I used `where("lower(name) LIKE lower(?)", params[:query] + '%')` instead, but I Iike yours.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, you have to use ILIKE instead of LIKE to do a case-insensitive pattern match.